# Massive jQuery update -> My ajax doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, json, jquery, updates

I've been using stackoverflow for months now as it really is the the most reliable resource I can think about. However, I now have my own question.

I'm working on a script that displays available courses in an HTML5 page using ajax after calling some php/MySQL interaction. I was using jQuery 1.4.1 (yeah... i know) and due to some interesting new plugins available, I updated to 1.10.2.

Now my page doesn't display the product of the PHP/SQL processing anymore, nor does the autoscroll work.
I did some search and didn't find any answer.
I was hoping you guys would see directly the incompatibility in my code, or the usage of a too old syntax.

Trigger :

```
<a class="internal-link" href="#" onclick="goToByScroll('reanimation');"></a>
```

Script :

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "kernel/appel-tableaux-ajax.php",
        dataType: "script",
        data:{type_cours : id},
        success: function(array){ 
                    var objet = JSON.parse(array);
                    var message = objet["message"];
                    var nombre = objet["nombre"];
                    $("#conteneur-tableaux").html(message);
                    $("#nombre-cours").html(nombre);
                    if(nombre==0)
                    {
                        $("#titre-section-tableaux").css("color","darkred");
                    }else{
                        $("#titre-section-tableaux").css("color","darkgreen");
                    }

                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#section-tableaux").offset().top},'slow');
    
        }
    });
}
```

PHP code (I erased stuff where mistakes are less probable) :

```
ob_start(); // I want to catch all the 'echos' to insert them in an array.

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
    
        // Lots of Date comparison stuff and many ECHOS.
    
}

$out = utf8_encode(ob_get_contents()); // --- I put every echos inside the 'OUT' variable.
ob_end_clean();
// --- I want to send back 2 things to my script, some infos about the courses available, and the total number of available courses. So I create an array.
$output_final = array ("message" => $out, "nombre" => $compteur_cours);
echo json_encode($output_final);
?>
```

As you can see, I'm a beginner in Ajax and jQuery usage.

**UPDATE :**

Thanks a lot to all those who already helped.
I tried the debug tools in Chrome, the php generates exactly what it's supposed to do, which means that my ajax is able to call the PHP code placed in kernel/appel-tableau-ajax.php. The Console.log() placed in the success case doesn't display anything.
I'm adding a screenshot of the syntax errors that Chrome detected. If someone could help me to understand how to handle those errors it would be wonderful.

[Link to the screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3591678/errors.png)

Also, Safari's debugger says : SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object".
I can't believe all this worked on the old jQuery version...

Thanks a lot, I hope I'm not asking too much!

Comment: What does `console.log(array);` give you in the `success` function?

Comment: I'm not really sure this is it, because it has nothing to do with the update, but you seem to expect `JSON`, but that `while` is also doing "many ECHOS", that might not be JSON. That's looking like a bug? You should check the console.log as nicklas says, and check out the request and result (e.g. use chrome, press f12, check the 'network' tab and look what your AJAX request actually did. Start debugging ;)

Comment: Hello both of you. Thank you for your answers. I tried to replace the function after my 'success' case by 'console-log(array)' but nothing happens. I guess the 'success' case fails to occur. As for the echos, the ob_start() and ob_get_contents() functions are supposed to make them invisible and just save to content in my array. I will edit my post to add some precision. Thanks to you guys !

Answer (score 0):

if your php code return json why the 'dataType' in your ajax is 'script'? try change it to json.
hope it will work! :)

Comment: Thank your very much for such a quick answer. As I said, I'm really new to that stuff and all I do is pretty much copy and past from other codes. I changed the dataType to json (and also tried JSON) but it doesn't help. I guess I will leave it on json just in case. Thanks again!

Comment: I updated my first post. If anyone of you experts could have a look it would be awesome !